# How to store variables correctly without storing them globally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I declare a variable called `foo` in the ready function. Normally, locally declared variables are deleted when the function ends right?

I want to use this variable in the event listener of `#someid`. I tried this and the `foo` variable is still accessible when a click-event occurs on `#someid`.

Why isn't this variable destroyed and still accessible, when the ready function ends? Is it safe to declare a variable and use it this way? I don't want to declare the variable globally, as I didn't.

EDIT:
Where are these event listeners and their variables stored?

**Here is my js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var foo = 0;

//random event listener
$('#someId').on('click', function() { foo++; }); //increment foo

});
```

Comment: Related: [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: `foo` is in the local `scope` of `$(document).ready` which is parent scope for `click-handler`

variables in the `outer-scope` of the `function` are accessible in the `function`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Also, there are no global variables in the code you have provided.

Comment: few things for you to look for ,a) when to use function/event in dom ready/outside. b) declaring variable globally,but initializing in function c) Closures

Comment: I know I did not declare foo globally. But after the execution of the ready function, all local variables are deleted. 
The event listener will be executed multiple times and it uses a deleted variable, or am I wrong? When the event listener is defined, is the foo variable copied or something?

Comment: The local variables are *not* deleted in this case even though the ready function has finished: read up on "closures".

Comment: Coming from a c++ background it was kind of confusing, but now I totally understand it. Thanks all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to use this variable in the event listener of '#someid'. I tried this and the foo variable is still accessible when a click-event occurs on '#someid'.

This is correct, your variable `foo` is still in scope, and therefore accessible.

> Why isn't this variable destroyed and still accessible?

Because both are in the scope of the ready function.

> I don't want to declare the variable globally.

You haven't, so don't worry. You have declared a variable which is local to the ready function, and not global.

Comment: Yes, but the ready function is executed only once. And after the execution of a function, all local variables are deleted. But the event listener will be executed multiple times and it uses a deleted variable, or am I wrong? When the event listener is defined, is the foo variable copied or something?

Comment: **please learn closures**. closures are exactly that, that variables will **not be deleted** after the function-call is terminated, as long as there is **still a reference** to them. like an other function that utilizes them, and is itself referenced by the event-listener, wich itself is referenced by the node it is attached to, wich is referenced by the DOM. So as long as there's such a chain from the global-object to your variable it won't be deleted. Aaaaaand this variable is *not static*, it belongs to this particular function-call.